# how to implement licensing for sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jquery, licensing

I create sharepoint app for office 365.I want to implement licensing function for that online sharepoint app ? 
using https://verificationservice.officeapps.live.com/ova/verificationagent.svc it is posible to implement licensing for sharepoint hosted app?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 SharePoint App Models: SharePoint Hosted App and Provider Hosted App.

**1. For SP hosted app:**
You can make a generate button to create a license key and store it in a custom list. Then when end-users access to your app, check if the value of licensing field existing or not. If yes, let them access your app functions. If no, alert to them for buying license.

**2. For Provider hosted app:**

**Step 1**: Create a database to manage licensing

**Step 2**: In provider hosted app, you implement code to connect to licensing database and check if the license is existed. If yes, display your app functions. If no, alert to end-users for them to ask for buying license.

The provider hosted app is a container that host your code so you can use any popular programming languages to implement like PHP, Java, .NET, JavaScript...

Comment: using https://verificationservice.officeapps.live.com/ova/verificationagent.svc it is posible to implement licensing for sharepoint hosted app?

Comment: Please noticed that we don't mention about authentication about sharepoint hosted app. My answer above are solutions for implement how to manage licenses inside the app. Normally, users have the right permission can access and use an app.
The link you post is just for authenticate an app.